# Why the time of a signal is an independent variable

Tags: signal-processing, wavelet, haar-wavelet, wavelet-transform

Can any one please explain clearly why the time of a signal is an independent variable while the amplitude is a dependent one? I referred to some results from google but i coul not figure it out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because appears not to be about coding but general understanding of maths/physics.

Answer (score 1):

Strange question. Definitely more philosophical than programming-related. Here's my view.

One explanation is that a signal is a [(mathematical) function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29) of time. That means that for each time you have one and only one amplitude value. In contrast, the same amplitude value could be found at several (or none) time instants. So if you considered amplitude as independent variable and time as dependent of amplitude, the relationship wouldn't be a function. It's easier to ask something **whose answer is known to be unique** (amplitude obtained at a given time) than it is to ask something that might have none, one, or arbirarily many answers (time instants corresponding to a given ampitude level).

Also, psychologically we are **more often interested** in finding out "what the signal value is at a given instant", as opposed to knowing "at which instants a given signal value is found". For example, questions of the type "what will the weather be like tomorrow?" are more common than "on which days from now on will the weather be sunny?". So the point of view of time as independent and amplitude as dependent on time seems more natural.

Answer (score 0):

The time is a universal independent variable because nothing can change the time. On multiple time instance there can be the same value of amplitude. But on two amplitudes there can not be one time. Independent variables are those which can not be changed with respect to other parameter.

Answer (score 0):

the `raw signal` what ever it is measuring it is a function of time "time-domain" which means if we plotted the "time-domain" we will get one axes for the time (t), which is independent, and another axes for the Amplitude (x(t)) which is dependent variable on the time.

Note that: the independent variable "time" could be continous or discrete. Continuos means the time could be represented as intervals eg: t=(0 -> 800). while the discrete time signal could be represented as a countable set, eg: t = (1/2,5/2,/8/2).

Also, if you have a signal with the independent variable represents the TIME, then this signal is multidimensional "more than one dimention"